# Accessing a function declares in a class in Javascript ES6 (ES2015? ES16?)

Tags: javascript, function, class, ecmascript-6

I created a small helper class:

```
import moment from 'moment';

export default class Format {
  formatDate(date) {
    return moment(date);
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to invoke it in a JSX template:

```
import React from 'react';
import Format from '/imports/helpers/format.js';

export default class ListingCard extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card">        
        {Format.formatDate(this.props.listing.created_at)}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

---

Using WebStorm, the Format class is found. But the method is not.

> ListingCard.jsx:22 Uncaught TypeError: _format2.default.formatDate is not a function

Any idea why?

Comment: `Format.prototype.formatDate` is the function. `class` is sugar for prototypes.

Comment: *"I created a small helper class:"* You shouldn't be using a class for that. Just export the function: `export default function formatDate() {}`. Or if you have more such functions: `export function formatDate() {}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use the `static` keyword to declare a **class method**.

```
export default class Format {
  static formatDate(date) {
    return moment(date);
  }
}
```

The reason for this is, if you do not use the `static` keyword, `formatDate` will be an **instance method**, meaning the method is only available on an *instance* of the class.

```
// e.g., how to use an instance method
var f = new Format();
f.formatDate(someDate);
```

---

@loganfsmyth makes a good remark; it's something I didn't think to address in my original answer.

If you don't plan on utilizing `Format` as a class, there's no point in declaring it as such.

```
// format.js
import moment from 'moment'
export function formatDate(date) { return moment(date); }

// otherfile.js
import {formatDate} from './format';
```

Comment: I like this approach better than using the `prototype`. It makes sense.

Comment: @SergioTapia don't fool yourself. `class` still makes use of prototypes. Class methods and instance methods are suited for different designs. They're both equally useful. `class` just hides away some of the ugly `prototype` syntax.

Comment: If you're just storing a set of functions, you might as well do `export function formatDate(){}` and `import {formatDate} from '...';` and not use the class at all.